# TypeScript Handbook: class static side example overcomplication

Tags: typescript

Came across example in `Classes -> Advanced Techniques` section http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-advanced-techniques

```
class Greeter {
    static standardGreeting = "Hello, there";
    greeting: string;
    greet() {
        if (this.greeting) {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
        else {
            return Greeter.standardGreeting;
        }
    }
}

var greeter1: Greeter;
greeter1 = new Greeter();
alert(greeter1.greet());

var greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter;
greeterMaker.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";
var greeter2:Greeter = new greeterMaker();
alert(greeter2.greet());
```

And explanation:

> Next, we then use the class directly. Here we create a new variable called 'greeterMaker'. This variable will hold the class itself, or said another way its constructor function. Here we use 'typeof Greeter', that is "give me the type of the Greeter class itself" rather than the instance type. Or, more precisely, "give me the type of the symbol called Greeter", which is the type of the constructor function. This type will contain all of the static members of Greeter along with the constructor that creates instances of the Greeter class. We show this by using 'new' on 'greeterMaker', creating new instances of 'Greeter' and invoking them as before.

My question: what is the purpose of introducing `greeterMaker` variable? Ultimately, it just holds the reference to the `Greeter` class.

We can write code below,

```
Greeter.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";
var greeter2:Greeter = new Greeter();
alert(greeter2.greet());
```

receive same result and not confuse ourselves with strangely looking

```
var greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter;
```

Am I missing something here?
Is construct `var maker: typeof Foo = Foo;` indeed useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is correct and simpler, but they took the intermediate step of assigning the `Greeter` type to a variable first before operating on it.

Dissecting that line of code, they are just saying:

```
var greeterMaker // there is a variable named greeterMaker
                : typeof Greeter // the static type of this variable is a constructor function for the Greeter class;
                                 = Greeter; // Assign the value of Greeter (the constructor function) to the variable greeterMaker
```

So in the end, `greeterMaker` and `Greeter` are the same thing. (because the code is doing `var greeterMaker = Greeter;`)

I can only assume that their example did it this way just to demonstrate that you can assign the "type of a type" as the static type of a variable.
In other words, `var greeterMaker: typeof Greeter;` says that the static type of `greeterMaker` is the constructor function for a `Greeter`, not an instance of `Greeter` and that is the value of the example.

Comment: Thanks! You made me realize that I was reading this line of code in the wrong order ( mine was `var greeterMaker: (typeof Greeter = Greeter);` ). However, I'm still wondering why we would want to use such a construct, in this case `greeterMaker`. I thing I need to read their explanation and your answer for at least 10 times to make everything clear :)

Comment: The reason is to demonstrate that you can pass around and potentially rename `Greeter` to something else like `Yesman` by just saying `var Yesman: typeof Greeter = Greeter`

Comment: But strangely you can't then `var yesman:Yesman = new Yesman();`

Answer (score 0):

I too puzzled over this exact example for several hours.  In the example, they wanted to show the difference between instantiating the class with `new Greeter()` and using `typeof Greeter`.  The confusing part is that they followed with

`let greeter2: Greeter = new greeterMaker();`
This skips right over/hides the difference.  Ignore the `greeter2` line for the moment and focus only on the code below, because this is where the difference can be seen.

```
let greeter1: Greeter = new Greeter(); // var greeter1 = new Greeter();

let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter; // var greeterMaker = Greeter;
```

If you log greeter1 and greeterMaker then the example makes sense as you can see the difference: `new Greeter()` is the object *class Greeter* and `typeof Greeter` is the class Greeter *constructor function*

```
console.log(greeter1); // Greeter{} <-- the greeter object

console.log(greeterMaker);
// function Greeter() {} <-- class Greeter's constructor function
// console.log(Greeter) results in the same: function Greeter(){}
```

It may still be confusing to see the `Greeter{}` object in the greeter1 log (which can be expanded in the console to show all of the class members)

```
Greeter {}
    └─  __proto__: Object
        ├─  constructor: Greeter()
        ├─  greet: ()
        └─  __proto__: Object
```

but the greeterMaker console log only shows the JavaScript code for the constructor

```
function Greeter() {
}
```

If you look at the paragraph above the example (from the link in this question) it starts to make sense.

> Here, 'var Greeter' *(in this case 'var greeter1')* **is going to be assigned** the constructor function. When we call 'new' and *run this function*, we get an instance of the class.

Hence we see the see the complete object in the console when logging `greeter1`(the constructor function *has already run* and the *instance* created, whereas `greeterMaker` only shows us the constructor, which must still be called to run in order to create an instance of the class Greeter.

Now back to

```
let greeter2: Greeter = new greeterMaker();
console.log(greeter2.greet());
```

like `Greeter()` we cannot directly call `greeterMaker().greet()`
-we will get an error

```
console.log(greeterMaker().greet());
// Value of type 'typeof Greeter' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

console.log(Greeter().greet());
// Value of type 'typeof Greeter' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
```

`Greeter()` and `greeterMaker()` reference the constructor which is not accessible without calling "new".  So the example is showing that you can instantiate a class with `new Greeter()` or create a *copy* of the class by using `typeof Greeter` which can then be called with `new greeterMaker()`.

I realize this is an old post, but I ran into this and thought I could shed a little more light on this in case someone needs a little more information on this example.  Cheers